# Reading files and replacing words with another one in a different file in python

Tags: python

I have two text files, hostname1 and command_file1.

Hostname1 would be:

```
[Host1]
dfwm2
dwm1-su2
[Host2]
cisb1
cisb2
[Othe]
b4
b8
```

command_file1 would be:

```
[1]
edit
run show 
exit
show  et-0/0/0 brief
show adjacency
show oamtest
edit
run
```

What I need to do is:

I need to replace [1] in Command_file1 with dfwm2 and then print the following lines like 'edit,run show,exit, etc' then again replace the [1] with dwm1-su2 and print the next lines.

What I did is:

I first read the Hostname1.txt and saved it in a dictionary:

```
def read_hosts(filename):
# Read the filename and store file content in a variable as list of lines. Variable - file_cont
hosts=collections.OrderedDict()
key=''
value=[]
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
    #if '[' in line and ']' in line:
        if line.startswith('[') and line.endswith(']'):
            key = line[1:-1]
            value = []
            hosts[key]=value
return hosts
```

The o/p that I am getting is

```
{'Host2': ['cisb1', 'cisb2'], 'Host1': ['dfwm2', 'dwm1-su2'], 'Others': ['b4', 'b8']}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You set `value = []` and `hosts[key] = value`??? You need to reindent your post code.

Comment: Hi @liliscent the value gets set to the next box as soon as it encounters a new box (if there is any). Thats why its value=[ ].

Comment: The code you posted will return a trivial dict, the value of every key is `[]`, not to mention the indentation error. If you just want to replace [1] in second file by every host name in the first file, you can simply skip all rows containing '['.

Comment: Hi @liliscent I have changed the dictionary to be an oredered dict, changed in the code as well, and in this function I am only returning the hostfile values. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to load the hostnames into a dict? If you're not using the headings (parts in '[]') just skip them?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't use the headers in the host file, I simply ignored lines that start with '[' in this code and return a list of values instead of a dict. If you do need the keep the headers from the file it would not be hard to change this code to support that.

The key here really is just using the [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function. If you have control over the format of the input files you might have more success using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting).

```
VARIABLESFILE = 'Hostname1'
TEMPLATEFILE = 'command_file1'
REPLACEMENTKEY = '[1]'

def get_host_list(hostfile):
    hosts = []
    with open(hostfile) as hf:
        for line in hf.read().splitlines():
            if line.strip().startswith('['):
                continue
            hosts.append(line)
    return hosts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read the template file
    with open(TEMPLATEFILE) as tf:
        template = tf.read()

    # Read variables file and get a list of values to replace in template
    values = get_host_list(VARIABLESFILE)

    for value in values:
        rendered_template = template.replace(REPLACEMENTKEY, value)
        # Save this result to a file or whatever you want to do with it
        print(rendered_template, end='\n----------\n')
```